# SQL order by convert

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a problem with ordering a query by converting longtext (b.meta_value) into a datetime. I am getting error 1064.
the format in my database is mm/dd/yyyy and **I tried** to `order by`, but I keep getting error 1064. Where is the problem?:

```
convert(convert(b.meta_value,char(30)),DATETIME, 101)
convert(DATETIME, convert(b.meta_value,varchar(30)), 101)
convert(DATETIME, STR_TO_DATE(b.meta_value, '%m/%d/%Y'), 101)
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
d.name as name,
b.post_id as post_id,
b.meta_value as meta_value 
FROM wp_posts a 
inner join wp_postmeta b 
on a.id=b.post_id 
inner join wp_term_relationships c 
on c.object_id=b.post_id 
inner join wp_terms d 
on c.term_taxonomy_id=d.term_id 
where meta_key in('px_event_from_date') 
  and a.post_type='events' 
  and a.post_status!='trash' 
  and d.term_id = 104 
  and STR_TO_DATE(b.meta_value, '%m/%d/%Y') <= CURDATE() 
order by convert(DATETIME, STR_TO_DATE(b.meta_value, '%m/%d/%Y')) desc 
limit 0,1
```

Comment: what is your goal? what is your source data value? and what do you want to get as result? simple convert is just `STR_TO_DATE('05/11/2015', '%m/%d/%Y')` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/423

Comment: I want to get DB entry with date closest to today, but the date column is in longtext and I can't get it to order by it (I have to convert it to datetime but I keep getting errors)

Comment: So just post the full query you try to order

Comment: SELECT d.name as name,b.post_id as post_id,b.meta_value as meta_value FROM `wp_posts` a inner join wp_postmeta b on a.id=b.post_id inner join wp_term_relationships c on c.object_id=b.post_id inner join wp_terms d on c.term_taxonomy_id=d.term_id where meta_key in('px_event_from_date') and a.post_type='events' and a.post_status!='trash' and d.term_id = 104 and STR_TO_DATE(b.meta_value, '%m/%d/%Y') <= CURDATE() order by convert(DATETIME, STR_TO_DATE(b.meta_value, '%m/%d/%Y')) desc limit 0,1    The error is near convert function

Comment: I guess you have to filter `wp_postmeta` with something like `wp_postmeta.meta_key`=`some_data_meta_key` because this table store many values and many TYPEs of values not only dates for your post https://codex.wordpress.org/File:WP3.8-ERD.png

Comment: Isn't 'longtext' a `LOB` [The BLOB and TEXT Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html)? Why are you holding a 'date' in this format? It is for 'really long strings' which you are not sure of what type of data they contain. Why not use 'DateTime' column type?

Comment: it's because it's wordpress theme that holds them in postmeta table which is longtext. It seems that using str_to_date was correct, I was trying to do it the long and wrong way

Comment: @MateuszBartkowski, thanks for the clarification - i have learned about wordpress today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `meta_key` filter in your `JOIN` something like `meta_key = 'my_date'` (because I don't know which meta key you are trying to catch):

```
SELECT 
d.name as name,
b.post_id as post_id,
b.meta_value as meta_value 
FROM wp_posts a 
inner join (
  SELECT 
     post_id,
     meta_value
  FROM wp_postmeta 
  WHERE meta_key = 'my_date'
) b 
on a.id=b.post_id 
  and  STR_TO_DATE(b.meta_value, '%m/%d/%Y') <= CURDATE() 
inner join wp_term_relationships c 
on c.object_id=b.post_id 
inner join wp_terms d 
on c.term_taxonomy_id=d.term_id 
where meta_key in('px_event_from_date') 
  and a.post_type='events' 
  and a.post_status!='trash' 
  and d.term_id = 104 
order by STR_TO_DATE(b.meta_value, '%m/%d/%Y') desc 
limit 0,1
```

Comment: I was getting b.meta_value of 'px_event_from_date' which is a longtext by post_id from wp-posts table. STR_TO_DATE was the correct function, I was overcomplicating it

Comment: You answered my question in the first comment, my db table was just bad. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using convert incorrectly. You need cast instead.

In your case, however, you need STR_TO_DATE:

```
select str_to_date(b.meta_value, '%d\/%m\/%Y') from ...
```

assume you have data value like '02/02/2015'